# EF 6 - setup sqllite from code

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I try to setup sqllite provider for entity framework from code (w/o web.config). I have prepared `DbConfiugration`:

```
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Data.SQLite.EF6;

namespace Infrastructure
{
    internal class MyDbConfiguration: DbConfiguration
    {
        public MyDbConfiguration()
        {
            SetDefaultConnectionFactory(new LocalDbConnectionFactory("v11.0"));
            SetProviderFactory("System.Data.SQLite.EF6", new SQLiteProviderFactory());
        }
    }
}
```

But when try to use DbContext, the following error is used:

> System.NotSupportedException: 'Unable to determine the provider name
>   for provider factory of type 'System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory'. Make
>   sure that the ADO.NET provider is installed or registered in the
>   application config.

How can I configure EF to use SQLite's provider in code, without using web.config?

Comment: You're missing the config, as the error says.  You should have something like `<provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />` in your config.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29129796/no-entity-framework-provider-found-for-ef-6-and-sqlite-1-0-96-0) post has a similar title, it may help.

Comment: @Amy I see, but the question is that can I set it programatically w/o web.config?

Comment: Your question was "what am i missing", not "can i do this without web.config".  To answer the new question, maybe.  Everyone does it with configuration though.  You might be hard pressed to find an example of someone doing it in code.

Comment: @Amy it is cleary written that I'd like to run EF from code (w/o web.config) -see first line.

Comment: I've edited your question to ask what you meant to ask, since what you actually asked wasn't what you were after.

Comment: Is `MyDbConfiguration` in the same assembly as your DbContext?

Comment: @mason yes. I have also tried to set hack from question linked by dcg, but the same error occurs.

Comment: If you were configuring Oracle, you would call `SetProviderServices` and pass `EFOracleProviderServices.Instance` as shown [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E56485_01/win.121/e55744/InstallEntityConfig.htm#ODPNT8266). Perhaps there's an equivalent you can do for SQLite? Just brainstorming here. That led me to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29904193/create-sqlite-database-using-entity-framework).

Comment: How about [EF6, SQLite won't work without App.confg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43615926/ef6-sqlite-wont-work-without-app-confg/43688403#43688403)